# Magento 1.9.2 - how to set checkbox in admin grid checked by default

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, checkbox

Is there any way to make all checkboxes checked in particular column in admin grid.

I want checkboxes checked by default in "skip" column. 
Here is a code for this column:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();

    $this->addColumn('skip', array(
        'header'     => Mage::helper('importexport')->__('Skip'),
        'type'       => 'checkbox',
        'name'       => 'skip',
        'field_name' => Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export::FILTER_ELEMENT_SKIP . '[]',
        'filter'     => false,
        'sortable'   => false,
        'align'      => 'center',
        'index'      => 'attribute_id'
    ));

   //other columns here

    if ($this->hasOperation()) {
        $operation = $this->getOperation();
        $skipAttr = $operation->getSkipAttr();
        if ($skipAttr) {
            $this->getColumn('skip')
                ->setData('values', $skipAttr);
        }
        $filter = $operation->getExportFilter();
        if ($filter) {
            $this->getColumn('filter')
                ->setData('values', $filter);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: check answer....

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
$this->addColumn('skip', array(
        'header'     => Mage::helper('importexport')->__('Skip'),
        'type'       => 'checkbox',
        'name'       => 'skip',
        'field_name' => Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export::FILTER_ELEMENT_SKIP . '[]',
        'filter'     => false,
        'sortable'   => false,
        'align'      => 'center',
        'index'      => 'attribute_id',
        'values'      => array(1,2) // add your values here
));
```

**just add key 'values'      => array(1,2) // your values**

> If you want default checked value for all you need to pass all value
>   in array or make new Grid Column Renderer

Comment: Isn't that the same thing? $this->getColumn('skip')
                ->setData('values', $skipAttr);

Comment: yes that should work. try it out

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.

Comment: from where you are calling  $this->getColumn('skip') ->setData('values', $skipAttr); ?

Comment: Do you guys know how to do this exactly? because i'm on this situation and dont know how to do that, on catalog_category_product, they can checkbox checked, but i'm follow them and doesn't checked at all. @@
the values i put in is a array just like them did. Like this (1,2)